# cordova 5.3.1 doesn't copy www folder ( in root folder of project) content to asset folder and app

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova 5.3.1 doesn't copy WWW folder ( root folder) content to asset folder and android app. As it was happening in cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13.

i am using following commands to build android app.

```
 cordova prepare android
 cordova compile android
```

i have also tried

```
 cordova build android
```

Comment: yes, i did. `cordova prepare android` isn't working but  `cordova compile android` is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found the solution. I was using node 5.0.0. Now problem is solved by node 4.0.0.

[found here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.0.0/)